# Make the elements of a string vector into elements of char

Tags: c++, string, parsing, vector, char

I'm a beginner and I can't make my head around how I can make the contents inside the string vector to become char and still be in the same element.

I am taking a file where it is multiple messages in the same line together. So this program creates a new line wherever there is the delimiter "3=Value" and stores that line into a string vector. Each line will get a checksumvalue which will need to take account of every character of the line.

I am struggling to see how I can make each element in the string vector to become a char so it can go through every character in the line/element to generate a checksumvalue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

std::vector<std::string> SortString(std::string str, std::string delimiter)
{
    std::size_t pos_previous = 0; // start of line
    std::size_t pos_current;      // end of line
    std::size_t delimiter_length = delimiter.length();

    std::string line_number;
    std::string full_message;
    std::string checksum_value = "checksum=";
    std::vector<std::string> vstr;
    while( (pos_current = str.find(delimiter, pos_previous)) != std::string::npos)
    { // looks for delimiter from previous position
        line_number = str.substr(pos_previous, pos_current - pos_previous);
        pos_previous = pos_current + delimiter_length; // start of line is now the end of the previous line.
        full_message = delimiter + line_number;
        std::size_t pos_checksum = 0;

        while( ( pos_checksum = full_message.find(checksum_value)) != std::string::npos )
            full_message.erase(static_cast<int>(pos_checksum), 6);
        vstr.push_back(full_message);
    }

    return vstr;
}

void GenerateCheckSum( char *b, long bLen )
{
// Takes each character and a method is used to give a unique number to a char and generate a value.
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("filename.extension");
    // stuff here
    while(file.is_open())
    {
        std::string delim = "3=VALUE";
        std::string message;
        std::getline(file, message);

    std::vector<std::string> v = SortString(message, delim);
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << v.at(i) << "\n";

        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for taking your time to help. Using older version of cpp

Comment: You can convert string within your vector to char array using stl function like the following `<stringvariable>.c_str()` then you can pass the char * to Generate Function

Comment: @Maddy what function would I need to use to get the string element in vector. Would vector.at(elementNumber) work?

Comment: use a range based for loop like  `for(string str : vstr) { char *p = str.c_str()}`

Comment: @AlexanderZhang: That's correct I missed it while typing :)